# When was the last case of Go'el Hadam (Blood Avenger) that we know about?

Tags: history

When was the last case of Go'el Hadam (Blood Avenger) that we know about? Other than reading about the avenger in the Torah I've never come across any actual cases of it.

Comment: Yoav considered himself a goel hadam for Avner's killing of Amasa.

Comment: IIRC, this case only applies when there are functioning refugee cities, therefore not after 722BCE. It is reasonable that the later, Second Temple sources remember no practical cases.